# why is my code overriding my base.html navbar?

Tags: html, django

So, I am creating a profile page and the JS script I need is overriding my base.html navbar. How can can I get it to not do that? Basically it's moving my navbar to the left only on this specific page. I am not sure how I can keep the navbar intact without taking the JS script entirely away.

**profile.html**

```
    {% extends "dating_app/base.html" %}

<title>Profile</title>

<!DOCTYPE html>
{% block head %}
<head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>


</head>

{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<title>Profile</title>

<div class="container">    
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">  <h4 style="color:#CB2603  "   >My Profile</h4></div>
                       <div class="panel-body">
                      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                       <img alt="User Pic" src="{{  profile.photo.url  }}"  id="profile-image1" class="img-circle img-responsive"> 


                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-8" >
                          <div class="container" >
                            <h2>{{ profile }}</h2>



                          </div>
                           <hr>
                          <ul class="container details" >
                            <h3   >About me</h3>
                                <p><span  style="width:50px;margin:50px"></span>{{ profile.description }}</p>

                          </ul>
                          <hr>
                        {% if user.id == profile.id %}
                            <p><a style="color:#CB2603 " href="{% url 'dating_app:update_account' profile.id %}">edit profile</a></p>
                        {% endif %}

                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


{% endblock content %}
```

**base.html**

```
    {% load bootstrap4 %}
{% load static %}

{% load unread_messages_counter %}

<!-- Navbar is located in this file -->


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>



    {% block head %}
    <title>Base</title>
    {% endblock %}

    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static  'css/notification.css' %}" type="text/css" class = "notification"/>
    <style>
    <!-- Add this tag -->
    {% block styles %}

    {% endblock %}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-md">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class= 'navbar-brand'  href="{% url 'dating_app:home' %}"><img src="{% static 'images/cupids_corner_logo.jpg' %}"><h5 style="color:red"></h5> </a>
        <button class= "navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div  class="collapse navbar-collapse"  >
          <ul class ="navbar-nav ml-auto" >


            {% if user.is_authenticated %}


                {% unread_messages request.user as user_unread_messages %}
                {% if user_unread_messages > 0 %}


                    <li class="nav-item"  >
                        <a class=  "notification" style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}" type="text/css" > 
                        <span>Inbox</span>
                        <span class="badge">{% unread_messages request.user %}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                {% else %}

                    <li class="nav-item">

                        <a style="color:brown"  href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}">    
                            <span>Inbox</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown"  href="{% url 'dating_app:view_matches' user.id %}">Matches</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown"  href="{% url 'dating_app:mingle' %}">Mingle</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:profile' user.id %}">My Profile</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:logout' %}">log out</a>
                </li>
            {% else %}

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:login' %}">login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:register' %}">register</a>
                </li>

            {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    </nav>

<!-- HEADER END -->


<!--Below is individual page will html will be rendered -->

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}

<hr class="my-4">

<!--Connect -->
<div class="container-fluid padding">
<div class="row text-center padding">
     <div class="col-12">
        <h2>Connect</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="col-12 social padding">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.instagram.com/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- FOOTER AREA BEGINS BELOW-->

<footer>
<div class="container-fluid padding">
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="{% static 'images/cupids_corner_logo.jpg' %}">
        <hr class="light">
        <p>703-309-9572</p>
        <p>rezazandirz@gmail.com</p>
        <p>100 Street Name</p>
        <p>City, State, 000</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <hr class="light">
        <h5>Our hours</h5>
        <hr class="light">
        <p>Monday: 9am-5pm</p>
        <p>Saturday: 10am-4pm</p>
        <p>Sunday: closed(like Chick-fil-A)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <hr class="light">
        <h5>Our satellite offices</h5>
        <hr class="light">
        <p>City, State, 00000</p>
        <p>City, State, 00000</p>
        <p>City, State, 00000</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <hr class="light-100">
        <h5>&copy;CupidsCorner.com</h5>
    </div>


</footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
      ================================================== -->
      <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

      <script src="../../assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `profile.html` you are extending `base.html`. This means that everything in your `profile.html` should be inside `{% block x %}` tags.

In your `profile.html` file, you currently have  in two places, and `<DOCTYPE>` which you don't need as this will come from your 'parent' template (`base.html`).

To overwrite the `<title>` just include it inside your `{% block head %}` section, as this is where it should be.

Inside your `{% block head %}` tags, there is no need to repeat `<head>` as you are already inside the head tags from your parent template at this point.

All of the above will result in the following:

```
{% extends "dating_app/base.html" %}

{% block head %}
    <title>Profile</title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}


<div class="container">    
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">  <h4 style="color:#CB2603  "   >My Profile</h4></div>
                       <div class="panel-body">
                      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                       <img alt="User Pic" src="{{  profile.photo.url  }}"  id="profile-image1" class="img-circle img-responsive"> 


                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-8" >
                          <div class="container" >
                            <h2>{{ profile }}</h2>



                          </div>
                           <hr>
                          <ul class="container details" >
                            <h3   >About me</h3>
                                <p><span  style="width:50px;margin:50px"></span>{{ profile.description }}</p>

                          </ul>
                          <hr>
                        {% if user.id == profile.id %}
                            <p><a style="color:#CB2603 " href="{% url 'dating_app:update_account' profile.id %}">edit profile</a></p>
                        {% endif %}

                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: @Rez That is not what is shown in your question - I have made a few changes. Please can you update your question to show the code, exactly as it is in your non-working example.

Comment: So I figured out what the issue is. The problem is I'm running bootstrap 4 on my base.html and the rest of my website, but the <head> on this page is running bootstrap 3. How can I change this to bootstrap 4 while keeping the code on profile.html still working because it relies on the scripts in the <head> section of profile.html